# message queue: call msgsnd return -1

Tags: linux, message-queue

It has been confusing me for two days, I use `msgsnd` to send a message but return -1, while the error number `errno` is 22(`EINVAL`) which means "Invalid argument". In the [document](https://linux.die.net/man/2/msgsnd), it shows this error will occur if the following condition meet:

```
Invalid msqid value, or nonpositive mtype value, or invalid msgsz value (less than 0 or greater than the system value MSGMAX).
```

In my code, `msqid` is 0 which is correct, while `mtype` is 16 and `msgsz` is 1600. The value `MSGMAX` in `/proc/sys/kernel/msgmax` is 8192 which is default and bigger than 1600. So I think all these conditions are fulfilled. But I suspect that it's `msgsz` problem because when I reducing the size 1600 to 1000, this message can be sent.

Here comes my code:

```
typedef struct
{
  MASK_BASE_UNIT   value[MASK_SIZE(MAX_PORTS)];
} PORT_MASK_t;

typedef struct _packet_
{
  unsigned char     data[MAX_PACKET_SIZE]; //MAX_PACKET_SIZE = 1558
  unsigned int      asic;
  unsigned int      pkt_len;
  unsigned int      source_port;
  PORT_MASK_t       dst_port_mask;
} PACKET_t;

typedef struct _packet_msg_
{
  unsigned int      appMask;
  PACKET_t          packet;
  int               ltcRequestId;
} MSG_t;

STATUS pkt_mux_packet_handler (MSG_t *msg)
{
    MSG_t msg_data;
    ...
    memset(&msg_data, 0, sizeof(msg_data));
    memcpy(&msg_data, msg, sizeof (msg_data));
    if (-1 == msgsnd (pkt_mux_info.recvMsgQid, &msg_data, sizeof(MSG_t), 0)) //sizeof(MSG_t) == 1600
    {
        printf("%s called, failed: errno: %s, error code:%d\n", __func__, strerror(errno), errno);
        fflush(stdout);
        return STATUS_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

There is another strange thing that if I clear the `data` array in the `msg_data->packet`, this message can be sent successfully.

Comment: Note that the documentation for msgsend() says the 1. member (mtype) is a `long` , not an `unsigned int`

Comment: @nos, I really did a test that `unsigned int` can also work

Comment: It can by chance if sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(long), however that will not be the case on 64 bit linux, in which case content of your PACKET_t will affect the actual message id as interpreted by the kernel.

Comment: @nos, thanks, I think you are right, this code is incorrect.